# Potential theory and examples of hyperharmonic functions

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, harmonic-analysis, potential-theory

This follows the book "Stratified Lie Groups and Potential Theory for Their Sub-Laplacians" by Bonfiglioli, Lanconelli, and Uguzzoni. In chapter 6, the book introduces abstract harmonic spaces and introduces the following notion in Definition 6.2.4.

Let $\mathcal{H}$ be a harmonic sheaf on $(E, \mathcal{T})$ and let $\Omega \in \mathcal{T}$ be open. A function $u: \Omega \rightarrow (-\infty, \infty]$ is called $\mathcal H$-hyperharmonic if $u$ is (1) lower semi-continuous, and (2) for every $\mathcal{H}$-regular open set $V \subset \overline{V} \subset \Omega$ one has
$$u(x) \geq \int_{\partial V} u(y)d\mu_x^V(y)$$
for all $x \in V$.

My question is: the book is quite abstract in its presentation and I can't get my head around what I'm supposed to think of. I can think of what a $\mathcal H$-regular set is and what a $\mathcal H$-harmonic measure is (for instance, by the Green's function and the representation formula or by the surface mean value theorem), but I can't think of what a $\mathcal H$-hyperharmonic function looks like for, say, the usual Laplace operator $\Delta$ on Euclidean space. (If more details on how $\mathcal H$-regular is defined or what $d\mu_x^V$ are needed then I will add this.)

Comment: Does this not correspond to what's usually called a superharmonic function? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subharmonic_function

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out - I jumped ahead and it seems the book distinguishes between a hyperharmonic function and a superharmonic function - in Def 6.2.1, it is superharmonic if it is hyperharmonic and the function $\varphi(x) = \int_{\partial V} u(y)d\mu_x^V(y)$ is itself harmonic, but in Thm 6.5.2 it characterises superharmonic functions as hyperharmonic functions s.t. $\{x \in V \mid u(x) < \infty\}$ is dense. The type of functions I'd think of would probably satisfy this, but do you think this is a noteworthy distinction to make by any chance?